# PESSIMISTIC_WRITE не работает в многопоточности

Tags: java, многопоточность, mariadb, транзакции, persistence

`Java 1.8`, `MariaDB 10.6`, `IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1 (Ultimate Edition)`.

У меня был следующий код:

```java
@Path("/operation")
@RequestScoped
public class OperationController {
    
    @EJB
    private OperationLocalBean operationBean;

    @POST
    @Path("/{id}")
    public void doOperation(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        operationBean.doOperation(id);
    }
}
```

```java
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class OperationLocalBean implements OperationBean {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "operation")
    private EntityManager em;
    
    @Override
    public void doOperation(int id) {
        Operation operation = em.find(Operation.class, id);
        em.detach(operation);
        
        if (!operation.isApplied()) {
            operation.do();
            operation.setApplied(true);
            em.merge(operation);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Существовала проблема, что когда два потока одновременно вызывали эндпоинт `/operation/{id}`, они одновременно считывали одно и то же значение из базы данных, вследствие чего одна операция выполнялась дважды.

Вместо `EnityManager#find`, который ранее использовался для чтения сущности из БД, я написал следующий метод:

```java
  public Operation getAndLock(int id) {
    final long lockTimeoutInMilliseconds = 1000L;

    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", lockTimeoutInMilliseconds);

    return em.find(Operation.class, id, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE, properties);
  }
```

Сейчас код метода `OperationLocalBean#doOperation` выглядит так:

```java
@Override
public void doOperation(int id) {
    Operation operation = getAndLock(id);
    em.detach(operation);
        
    if (!operation.isApplied()) {
        operation.do();
        operation.setApplied(true);
        em.merge(operation);
    }
}
```

Теперь проблема ушла, второй поток читает значение из БД только после того, как первый поток закроет свою транзакцию.

Но я снова сталкиваюсь с той же проблемой, если ставлю точку остановы на последнюю строку метода:

```java
return em.find(Operation.class, id, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE, properties);
```

Когда первый поток останавливается на данной строке, я жду полсекунды, отпускаю его, после чего на строке останавливается второй поток, и я отпускаю и его. После этого операция выполняется два раза подряд, т.е. второй поток считывает значение из БД до того, как транзакция первого потока завершится.

Почему так происходит? Является ли это сайд-эффектом от использования дебаггера?

Comment: Дебаггер никак на это не влияет. Из того, что вы описали с точками останова, не видно, что второй поток считывает значения пока первый _еще в_ транзакции. Использование `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` в транзакции не дает двум транзакциям выполятся _одновременно_, но после того, как первая завершилась, вторая продолжит свое выполнение, и если вы там не делаете никакой специальной проверки, что вторую операцию делать нельзя, то она будет выполнена.  Покажите, как вы используете `getAndLock`.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA дополнил вопрос

Comment: Во-первых, `OperationLocalBean.doOperation` должен выполнятся в одной транзакции. В зависимости от используемого контейнера (главным образом от его поведения для методов EJB по умолчанию и доп. настроек этого поведения) для вашего кода это можеть быть не так. Во-вторых, зачем делаете `detach`? Я не знаю точно, но 98%, что это снимает блокировку из БД, т.к. сущность убирается из контекста, а это по логике означает и снятие блокировки.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA по поводу транзакции - что я могу сделать, попробовать объявить её явно над методом doOperation? А по поводу detach - там он действительно нужен, потому что я привожу лишь самые значимые части кода, а там ещё выполняются некоторые операции с сущностью, из-за чего надо делать detach

Comment: Все же, зачем нужен detach? С ним работать не будет.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA сейчас не скажу, не у компьютера. Посмотрю завтра) Попробую избавиться от детача

Comment: Что касается транзакций, то нужно убедиться что включены container managed transactions и тогда по умолчанию у stateless бина методы будут выполнятся в транзакции. Как именно это делать зависит от используемого контейнера. Я бы в логе БД убедился, что при вызове метода стартует и при выходе из метода фиксируется транзакция.